# How do you change the proxy of a requests.Session() Object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, python-requests

**General Background:**

I have a list of proxies, and I have a list of PDF url's. I am downloading these PDF's.

I want to be able to switch proxies every couple of downloads.

I've seen the following in a few answers, but are all of the proxies used at once? Or is it random from the dict of proxies? How do I choose which proxy to use?

```
proxies = {
    'https': 'http://username:password@ip:port', 
    'https': 'http://usernamepassword@ip:port',
    'https': 'http://usernamepassword@ip:port',
    'https': 'http://usernamepassword@ip:port',
    'https': 'http://usernamepassword@ip:port',
    'https': 'http://usernamepassword@ip:port'
}
```

Here is an example sample of the current code I have

**My Code:**

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {"Username":"usr", "Password":"psw"}
url = "https://someSite.com"
#Logging into the site
s.post(url, data=data) #add proxies=proxies here?

for download_url in PDFLinks:
    temp = s.get(download_url).content
```

I have a list of usable proxy servers

```
https_proxy_list = "https://IP:port", "https://IP:port", "https://IP:port"
```

**How do I change the proxy of a request.Session() object? for both POST and GET**

By changing the proxy I don't have to re-log into the site, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a list of proxies and then cycle through them

```
s = requests.Session()

proxyList = ['Just imagine there are a few proxies here']

for item in proxyList:
    r2 = s.get(login_url, proxies = {'https' : item}, verify=False)


    print r2.status_code
    if r2.status_code == 200:
        print "It worked"
        usable_IP.append(item)


    print usable_IP
print usable_IP
```

This is the code I'm currently using and it solved my problem that I was having. 12/13/2017